# Programatic navigation in Visual SourceSafe

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Maybe this is a very simple problem, but I just can't figure it out. Is there any way to navigate to a certain folder in MS Visual SourceSafe from an external application?

Maybe some sort of command line parameter? (of course that would only work if VSS is closed). Or is there a solution that would also work if VSS is already opened? (COM?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is VBS sample code to start programmatically control VSS:

```
const SS_INI_PATH = "с:\db\vss\srcsafe.ini"
const SS_LOGIN = "login"
const SS_PASSWORD = "password"

set obj = CreateObject("SourceSafe")

obj.Open SS_INI_PATH, SS_LOGIN, SS_PASSWORD

set objPrj = obj.VSSItem("$/project1")

' call below any objPrj methods
```

Help on object interfaces you can find here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.sourcesafe.interop(v=vs.80).aspx